# Laravel join and distinct

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel, I have a query which is:

```
$productsModel->join('tags', 'tags.item_id', '=', 'products.id')
      ->select('products.*', 'tags.item_id')
      ->distinct();

DB tables looks like this:
| products | tags    |
 ----------|---------|
| id       | id      |
|          | item_id |
```

products has a one to many relationship with tags, which creates issues when joining tables. As an example, I need to query products based on multiple tags, but I need to show only one product.

Comment: Your query and database "schema" do not match. Is `item_id` on `table_a` or `table_b`? Is `$model` an instance of a record from `table_a` or `table_b`?? And what do you want to be distinct? A or B?

Comment: Thanks. Spelling mistakes - updated.

Comment: What's the condition to query one product?

Answer (score 4):

Okay. You're going to have to provide a little more context.

From the looks of things, you have a 1:n relationship, where TableA has many TableB. Therefore, if you do a join, you may have multiple TableB records joined to TableA records, which is fine.

But then, if you want to select a distinct TableA record, which of the many possible TableB records should be returned, if there's more than one?

An easy way to achieve what you're asking is to use `GROUP BY`.

```
$tableA->selectRaw('table_a.*, MAX(table_b.item_id) AS item_id')
    ->join('table_b', 'table_a.id', '=', 'table_b.item_id')
    ->groupBy('table_a.id')
    ->get();
```

It's also worth mentioning that selecting `table_b.item_id` isn't necessary, because the value will always equal `table_a.id`. Just saying.

**Edit** - based on your updated question, if you just want to find products with specific tags, you can use `WHERE IN` and just not select a field from `table_b`.

```
$tableA->select('table_a.*')
    ->join('table_b', 'table_a.id', '=', 'table_b.item_id')
    ->whereIn('table_b.id', [1, 2, 3])
    ->groupBy('table_a.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: the catch is that when you use ->select('table_a.*', 'table_b.item_id') ir returns an error. `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #26 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'table_b.item_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause;`

Comment: My bad. This goes back to my question as to how you're going to decide which `TableB` record to use. I've just thrown an aggregator function on there to make MySQL happy, but you'll need to answer that question.

Comment: The first available or the groupBy would work for me actually.

Comment: But you are right, my issue is not with laravel in particular, but as to how aggregate this.

Comment: Update your question with specifics as to what you're trying to do. Why are you joining the tables? What do you want out of table B?

Comment: Updated. Been banging my head for far too long looking for a simple solution which, I think, resulted in brain damage :/

Comment: Hey, sorry I didn't see your reply. Are you still having problems?

Answer (score 3):

```
$tableA->select('table_a.id')
->join('table_b', 'table_a.id', '=', 'table_b.item_id')
->whereIn('table_b.id', [1, 2, 3])
->groupBy('table_a.id')
->get();
```

Select only that column which you want to group by.